# How can I pass an object parameter to an Entry event in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, xamarin.forms.entry

I have implemented a `ListView` that is binded to an `ObservableCollection` and I need to update each item when the entry fields are changed. I am using the completed event but it only passes the entry value to the completed event function and I don't know what object I am editing.

Is there any way to pass an object parameter to these entry events so that I can update the correct object? Or is there a better approach to doing this?

UPDATE

This is my list view code

```
<ListView 
            x:Name="DrawReturnList" 
            RowHeight="65" 
            BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding SCSDraw}"
            ItemSelected = "OnItemTapped"   
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="false"
            Margin="0, -10, 0, 0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     Orientation="Vertical"
                                     Padding="10">

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                              <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="90" Padding="0, 10, 0, 0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding PubDateShort3}" FontSize="18"/>
                              </StackLayout>

                              <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                                      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                                      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                      <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0, 10, 0, 0">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding InitialDraw}" FontSize="18"/>
                                      </StackLayout>
                                      <StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                            <Entry IsEnabled="{Binding ACLockFL, Converter={StaticResource not}}" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Draw" Text="{Binding Draw, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                      </StackLayout> <!-- end Draw -->
                                      <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                                            <Entry IsEnabled="{Binding ACLockFL, Converter={StaticResource not}}" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Returns" Text="{Binding Returns, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                      </StackLayout> <!-- end Return -->
                                    </Grid>


                              </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout><!-- end input group -->



                        </StackLayout> <!-- end Draw & Return Section-->
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView> <!-- end list view -->
```

This is binded to an Observable Collection that is in my ViewModel.

What I need to do is be able to edit each individual list item with its respective entry and have that be saved to its respective object. I tried the completed event on the Entry but I cant pass a parameter to this. How should I approach this?

UPDATE

MODEL

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Collector.Helpers;

namespace Collector
{
    public class AC_SCSDraw : EntityData, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {   
    private int draw;
    private int returns;

    public decimal CarrierID { get; set; }
    public decimal RspID { get; set; }
    public string RspName { get; set; }
    public decimal SCSDrawID { get; set; }
    public decimal PubID { get; set; }
    public string PubDesc { get; set; }
    public string WeekDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
    public string PubDateShort3 { get; set; }
    public int Draw
    {
        get { return draw; }
        set
        {
            draw = value;
            OnPropertyChange("Draw");
        }
    }
    public int Returns 
    {
        get { return returns; }
        set
        {
            returns = value;
            OnPropertyChange("Returns");
        }
    }
    public int InitialDraw { get; set; }
    public bool ACLockFL { get; set; }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChange(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
}
```

ViewMODEL

```
ObservableCollection<AC_SCSDraw> scsDraw = new ObservableCollection<AC_SCSDraw>();
    public ObservableCollection<AC_SCSDraw> SCSDraw
    {
        get { return scsDraw; }
        set
        {
            scsDraw = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SCSDraw");
        }
    }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet, so that we see what you tried at least. Otherwise it's almost impossible to help

Comment: @Joehl please see above update.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to change the value in an entry and save this changes depending on the underlying object.

One way to detect the change in the entry is, you need to check the changes in the property of your item-model (with the help of the `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Either directly in the `Set`-part or you register the `OnPropertyChanged`-Event of your item-model.

Here is an example for your property `Draw` (first entry)

```
public string Draw
{
    get { return _draw; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _draw) return;

        _draw= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Draw");

        // Here you can save your object
    }
}
private string _draw;
```

The disadvantage is, that you save your object on every charachter-change in the entry (that's not really smooth).

My suggestion is, that you either add a "save" button with a command (on this command you can send an additional command-property -> your item)

Or you implement a separate page to modify each item (this is the clearest way from to point of the user interface). But it depends on your use case.

Comment: The way I am binding the listView is to an Observable Collection. Would this approach be the same? Does the RaisePropertyChange declaration go in the model of my observable collection object type?

Comment: That's for the source. But I am talking about the proeprty behind the `AC_SCSDraw`-Item

Comment: OK, so I have implemented your suggestion on the model but I still dont get the onProperty change to work. I have added my ViewModel code and my model code in the question so you can see what I did.

Comment: Maybe it's because the property is an integer. This works only if you just enter integer values in the entry

Answer (score 0):

Bind the listview's selecteditem property and reference that when whichever entry event you choose to use completes.

```
<ListView
    x:Name="myListview"
    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"       
>
```